# Can we convert the numbers to a custom string?

Tags: r

This is my data

```
decay<- c("None", "None", "11, 55, 64", "None", "54, 66, 74", "47, 74, 55")
```

I want to convert all the numeric lists to `"Yes"`. How can I do this?

Comment: How about converting everything that is not None to Yes?

Answer (score 3):

Probably you need :

```
decay[grepl("\\d", decay)] <- "Yes"
decay
#[1] "None" "None" "Yes"  "None" "Yes"  "Yes"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `gsub`:

```
> gsub(".*\\d.*","Yes",decay)
[1] "None" "None" "Yes"  "None" "Yes"  "Yes"
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try the opposite, anything that is not "None" is "Yes":

```
decay[ decay != "None" ] <- "Yes"
decay
# [1] "None" "None" "Yes"  "None" "Yes"  "Yes"
```

Comment: Nice and simple.